# How to fix TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, express

I got simple query where I want to select all from aliases table.
Before all works fine but I did npm update.

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

```
 public async aliasesList(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> { 
            const aliases = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM aliases');
                res.json(aliases);
        }
```

But when I trying to execute this I got strange error:

```
(node:20996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'
    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'
    --- property '_object' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:27:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:4:12)
    at aliasesList (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:35:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projekty\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
(node:20996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with 
a non-zero exit code.
```

There is console.log of aliases.
I tried also await and without await

```
Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error:
      at Pool.query (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
      at C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:29:36
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:4:12)
      at aliasesList (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:39:16)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at next (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM aliases',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null
}
```

Output after await:

```
(node:32140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'
    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'
    --- property '_object' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:30:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\rad\Desktop\Projects\inv\backend\app\controllers\aliasesController.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:32140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32140) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with 
a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: can you please log here how does the query response looks ? the one you are passing to res.json?

Comment: @Odinn check edit

Comment: Please output the result after using await @MarcinDomorozki

Comment: do console.log(aliases) and then see what it prints @MarcinDomorozki after await

Comment: @Shubh under "There is console.log of aliases." is this output

Answer (score 0):

OK cool, you can see in the output that you have a circular JSON object right? what I suggest you choose a specific field to send for example:

```
public async aliasesList(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> { 
  const aliases = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM aliases');
  res.json(aliases._results);
}
```

Or something of that sort to just select what you need instead of sending the entire object which has a circular structure.

Comment: results does not exist on type 'Query'

Comment: I just gave it as an example, you might need to select something else not blindly copy my code example :) Look at examples on how to use that library you are using to query, maybe it's `.values` which is undefined in ur case but try to figure out what you need to extract from the return of the query function to pass to render, we already know that it's not the entire return value